# Formula to get the amount of points for each player

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say I had a group of ten people who did a race, and these were these results:

Player A: First place

Player B: Second place

Player C: Third place

Player D: Fourth place

... and so on.

So because Player A won, he gets ten points (the amount of players). Player B gets 9, Player C gets 8, and so on.

**Is there a formula/equation I can use to calculate the amount of points for a player given the amount of players** (like ten) **and the place of the player** (like sixth)**?**

Answer (score 0):

For $10$ players, you could use that the $k$-th place finisher gets $11-k$ points.

See if you can extend this idea to a more general field of $n$ players.

Comment: (number of players + 1) - finished place

Comment: That looks good.